# What does CAST(SUBSTRING()AS INTEGER)=x do?

Tags: sql, firebird

I am having an exam on SQL which I have rarely ever worked on. While going through the study material I encountered this example:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE
CAST (SUBSTRING (attribute_name from x for y) AS INTEGER) =z;
```

Now, I am guessing that this would delete a specific line, where an attribute name would be specified in the code, but am unsure.

Comment: From [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/10676716): *Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.*

Comment: as said, I don't have much clue about SQL overall, and I did give my guess as I clearly have no clue what else it could do. Will check the link tho, thanks for the heads-up

Comment: fixed the question as I've found that the code here was faulty... back to start?

Comment: The part after _EDIT_ seems to be a separate question. Please only ask one question per question on stack overflow. I'll edit out the second part, if you want to ask another question, post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `substring()` function extracts part of string (from the column `attribute_name`) from the position numbered `x` for `y` characters (or until position `x + y - 1`).  For instance `1 to 3` would be the first three characters.

This is then converted to an integer and compared to another value.

Rows where the comparison returns "true" are deleted.

Comment: so in case that numbers would be x=2, y=1 and z=3, that would mean..?

Comment: my bad, I have incorrectly written down the code, it seems to be `... FROM x FOR y ...`. Does that mean in any way a similar answer?

Comment: @Nobody The `FROM .. TO ..` syntax does not exist. But `FROM x FOR y` means from position x for z characters, so `FROM 1 FOR 3` means the first three characters (characters 1, 2, 3), `FROM 2 FOR 3` mean characters 2, 3, 4, etc. See https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-substring

Comment: so I guess I mark this answer as correct, even though, the comment in it really explained it?